# Gradle not working properly after Update · Issue #25820

Tags: flutter, gradle, exception, visual-studio-code

- Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
- Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
- ```
     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
  ```
- ```
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
  ```
- ```
     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
  ```
- ```
     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
  ```
- ```
     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
  ```
- ```
     at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
  ```
- ```
     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
  ```
- ```
     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
  ```
- ```
     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
  ```
- ```
     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
  ```
- ```
     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
  ```
- ```
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
  ```
- ```
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
  ```
- ```
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
  ```
- ```
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990)
  ```
- ```
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
  ```
- ```
     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
  ```
- ```
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
  ```
- ```
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
  ```
- ```
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
  ```
- ```
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
  ```
- ```
     at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
  ```
- ```
     at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
  ```
- ```
     at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
  ```
- ```
     at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
  ```

-Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
-Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         1.3s
-Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Did you update Flutter or Gradle ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a networking issue. The usual is that you need to [let Gradle know about any proxy](https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) it should use for connecting to servers outside of your company network.